# Angular "Module is not available" when switching to webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

My project is trying to switch from pure Javascript scripts to webpack. We have an html file, game.html, that has the following content:

```
<html>
    ...
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    ...
    <div ng-app="visualizerApp" ng-controller="VisualizerController as ctrl">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</html>
```

before switching to webpack, we just had a long list of scripts.

The angular module is created in a file app.js

```
import angular from 'angular';

class VisualizerController {...}

VisualizerController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];

angular.module('visualizerApp', []).controller('VisualizerController', VisualizerController);
```

before switching, the file was identical except for the import statement.

When opening the html file, we get an error in the console:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module visualizerApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'visualizerApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

edit: my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const mapType = require('./root/visualizer/js/map/PluginManager').mapType;


module.exports = {
    entry: './plugins/root/visualizer/js/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: '../game_logs/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /tests/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['babel-preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            mapPlugin: path.resolve(__dirname, 'map/' + mapType),
        }
    }
};
```

library versions:

```
├── angular@1.6.8
├── babel-cli@6.26.0
├── babel-loader@7.1.2
└── webpack@3.10.0
```

Comment: Is game.html in `../game_logs`?

Comment: It is. I did simplify the file structure here a bit, but all my paths are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like angular is loaded but not your other scripts. I would start by looking at bundle.js to make sure that what you expect to be there is actually there.

You haven't shared your webpack configuration so it's hard to say definitively what's happening. Webpack changes the dynamic of how your scripts are loaded.

I would also suggest using `angular.bootstrap` in order to bootstrap your application instead of `ng-app`.

Try the following:

```
<html>
    ...
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    ...
    <div id="visualizerApp" ng-controller="VisualizerController as ctrl">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</html>
```

And in your Javascript:

```
import angular from 'angular';

class VisualizerController {...}

VisualizerController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];

angular
    .module('visualizerApp', [])
    .controller('VisualizerController', VisualizerController);

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    let container = document.querySelector('#visualizerApp');
    angular.bootstrap(container, ['visualizerApp'])
});
```

`angular.bootstrap` allows you to manage when your application is bootstrapped. Not just when angular loads.

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hahgdz5g/) which uses angularjs 1.5.6 and ES5.

Comment: I tried your solution and it did not work for me. Also, the compiled code seems to be correct.
I edited my original post and added the config file

Comment: Hmm...I've created a small project isolated to just these files. I excluded the mapPlugin configuration in your webpack config and everything works fine. Which version of webpack, angular, and babel are you using? Any other browser console errors?

Comment: ├── angular@1.6.8

├── babel-cli@6.26.0

├── babel-loader@7.1.2

└── webpack@3.10.0

There is another error in the console, the line `if ($scope.visualizer && $scope.visualizer.canvas)` throws `Cannot read property 'visualizer' of undefined`

Comment: @Bary12 Those are the same versions I am using. I would look into that other error.